# Gas estimation failed in solidity leaseProperty function

Tags: solidity, remix, gas-limit, gas-estimate

i am creating smart contract for my property leasing problem
all function are work good in hedera network but the leaseProperty function is getting below error and transaction is failed if we forcefully send transaction
[image]

my function is below in solidity

```
//function to lease property
function leaseProperty(uint256 productId)
    external
    payable
    returns (uint256)
{
    Property storage property = properties[productId];
    // address user=msg.sender;
    require(property.list && !property.lease,"Property is not listed or property is already leased by other tenant.");
    // require(user!=property.owner,"owner can't lease their own property");
    require(msg.value>=property.price,"please send the exact amout to lease property.");

    property.tenant = msg.sender;
    property.startTime = block.timestamp;
    property.lease = true;

    emit PropertyLeased(
        productId,
        property.owner,
        msg.sender,
        msg.value,
        property.leaseTime
    );

    return productId;
}
```

can anyone give suggation it help me a lot

Comment: Are you passing the ether amount in wei greater than or equal to `property.price` in the **VALUE** input field of your Remix?

Make sure that you satisfy both of the `require` conditions, while calling your function.